# Class Acme\NBBundle\Entity\History_state is not a valid entity or mapped super class after moving project

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with my Symfony2 project.

I moved my working project to another server and it stopped working.
Here's the error I got:

```
Class Acme\NBBundle\Entity\History_state is not a valid entity or mapped super class
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/pGSJxsse) is the code,  which seems to be Ok, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in in your Class annotations.

Try with this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="history_state")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class History_state
```

I think you have forgotten `@ORM\Entity`. Also, if you have associate and custom *EntityRepository* in this line you have to import it correctly:

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourProject\YourBundle\Entity\YourRepository")
```

Comment: oh yes! thank you very much. i just needed to add another annotation

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="history_state")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

right before class declaration×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes